scales = free not working in facet_grid and geom_col
I have the following graph in ggplot and i've used facet_grid (the image only shows facet b) but I can't get scales=free to work in facet_grid so that the attribute levels with less than 6 bars shrinks to take up less space accordingly.
I have indicated where I have tried to do this with  ####'s

ggplot code:
     #  Plot 5
    # List of scenario numbers to filter out to remove all the bases cases except for 0
    scenarios_to_remove <- c("1.2", "9.2", "9.3", "1.3", "1.4", "10.2", "1.5", "1.6", "1.7", 
                             "5.2", "11.2", "11.3", "5.3", "5.4", "12.2", "5.5", "5.6", "5.7")
    
    # Filter out rows with specified scenario numbers
    filtered_df <- filtered_predictions %>%
      filter(!scenario_no_in_r_script %in% scenarios_to_remove)
    
    # Calculate the range of rel_change
    x_range <- range(filtered_predictions$rel_change)
    
    
    Plot5 <- 
      ggplot(data = filtered_df, 
             mapping = aes(x = rel_change,
                           fill = scenario,
                           y = factor(attribute_level, levels = c(
                             "FDA approval in 2 years", 
                             "FDA approval in 1 year", 
                             "FDA approval in 6 months",
                             "FDA approval now", 
                             "High certainty", 
                             "Moderate certainty", 
                             "Low certainty", 
                             "Very low certainty")))) +
      geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single")) +
      theme_article() +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("Base" = "darkgrey", 
                                   "Completely disabled" = "seagreen4", 
                                   "Bed or chair > 50% of waking hours" = "seagreen3", 
                                   "Up and about more than 50% of waking hours" = "seagreen2",
                                   "Able to carry out light work" = "seagreen1",
                                   "6 mth life expectancy" = "steelblue4", 
                                   "1 yr life expectancy" = "steelblue3", 
                                   "2 yr life expectancy" = "steelblue2", 
                                   "3 yr life expectancy" = "steelblue1",
                                   "Completely disabled and 6 mth life expectancy" = "purple4",
                                   "Able to carry out light work and 3 yr life expectancy" = "purple1")) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = rel_lower, xmax = rel_upper), position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single")) +
      labs(title = "Average marginal component effect on choice probability") +
      ylab("Attribute Levels") +
      xlab("Percentage change in probability of choosing drug relative to base case") +
      facet_grid(attribute ~ ., 
                 scales = "free_y", 
                 space = "free_y", 
                 drop = TRUE) + ############################
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(floor(x_range[1]), ceiling(x_range[2]), by = 0.2),  # Adjust breaks based on the range
                         minor_breaks = seq(floor(x_range[1]), ceiling(x_range[2]), by = 0.1),  # Adjust minor breaks
                         labels = percent_format()) +  # Format labels as percentages
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5, size = 8),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8, margin = margin(t = 15)),  # Adjust margin to move the title down
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8),
            legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
            legend.title = element_text(size = 8),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 8),
            legend.position = "bottom",
            strip.text = element_text(size = 8, color = "black"),
            panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "grey80", size = 0.25))+  # Major vertical grid lines
      # panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(color = "grey80", size = 0.25)) +  # Minor vertical grid lines
      guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Scenario", label = "Scenario", ncol = 2))
    
    Plot5 <- tag_facet(Plot5) # Add in the a and b labels
    
    Plot5

>     dput(filtered_df[1:4, ])
structure(list(attribute = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Level of certainty", 
"FDA approval time"), class = "factor"), attribute_level = c("Very low certainty", 
"Low certainty", "Low certainty", "Low certainty"), prob_drug_a = c(0.3108, 
0.4578, 0.4601, 0.4611), sd = c(0.009709, 0.006872, 0.007545, 
0.009267), lower = c(0.2936, 0.444, 0.4446, 0.4433), upper = c(0.3267, 
0.4699, 0.4734, 0.4755), abs_change = c(0, 0.147, 0.1647, 0.1655
), rel_change = c(0, 0.472972973, 0.557549086, 0.559878214), 
    rel_lower = c(0, 0.428571429, 0.505077861, 0.499661705), 
    rel_upper = c(0, 0.511904762, 0.602572783, 0.608592693), 
    scenario_no_in_r_script = c(1.1, 2.1, 9.6, 2.3), scenario = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 3L, 5L), levels = c("Base", "Completely disabled", "Bed or chair > 50% of waking hours", 
    "Up and about more than 50% of waking hours", "Able to carry out light work", 
    "6 mth life expectancy", "1 yr life expectancy", "2 yr life expectancy", 
    "3 yr life expectancy", "Completely disabled and 6 mth life expectancy", 
    "Able to carry out light work and 3 yr life expectancy"), class = "factor"), 
    explanation = c("Cert = 1", "Cert = 2", "Cert = 2, QOL = 3", 
    "Cert = 2, QOL = 1")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

This said I think you are misunderstanding how scales="free" works. scales="free" will free the x and y scale which in case of a discrete scale will drop all unused levels of the variable mapped on x or y per panel (or per row/column in case of facet_grid). However what you are looking for is to free the space according to the number of categories of the variable mapped on fill.

I think you're expecting facet _grid() to do something it isn't designed to do. facet_wrap() would be a better option.
The ways scales = "free" works can be illustrated as follows:
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  grp = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"), 
  cat = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "x", "x", "y", "y"), 
  id = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
  value = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 26, 27, 28, 99))

ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(axes = "all", scales = "free", rows = vars(grp), cols = vars(cat))

The axes are "free", but the y-axes are still the same for each row and the x-axes are the same for each column.
